# Vue 2 : get route on Vue created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue 2 , How to get route name on Vue created. I have tried using `Vue.prototype.$route` , still unable to get route data.

```
const newFunc = new Vue({
    created () {
      console.log(this.$route.name);
    },
    data () {
    },
    methods: {
    }
  })
  export default newFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the name set on the router, otherwise name will be undefined. For example...

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: "/", 
    component: Home, 
    name: "Home"  // Make sure route is named
  },
];
```

and then in the component, you should be able to access it in the `mounted` hook and not `created`

```
mounted() {
  console.log(`Route name is: ${this.$route.name}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi, not component, is js file declare `new Vue`